# How to set optional arguments in jinja2

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

I have used jinja2 to generate a json template. The json template is generated as expected. However, How do I make some parameters optional. For instance, In the below template `sam, uri_2 and uri_3` are optional. When I don't pass the values for them  in `template.render`, I don't want those parameters returned in the template. Currently, empty  values are returned for those parameters.

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template(''' 
        {
          "start": "{{start}}",    
          "end": "{{end}}",
          "sam": "{{sam}}",
          "res": "{{res}}",
          "uris": 
          [
             "{{uri_1}}",
             "{{uri_2}}",
             "{{uri_3}}"
          ]
        }   

        ''')

        payload = template.render(start=1560009000, end=1560009000, res=3, uri="abc.com")
```

output:

```
{"end": "1540995788", "res": "3", "sam": "", "start": "1540390988", "uris": ["abc.com", "", ""]}
```

Comment: well jinja2 has `{% if ... %}` tags...

Comment: @RobinZigmond I tried ' if ' , i see the optional params getting printed with value = None. I don't want that param to be in the template at all

Comment: You can use the if/endif construct that @RobinZigmond suggested to conditionally remove parts of your template. If you've tried it and it didn't work, show us what you tried and we'll see if we can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of parameters not passed at all (e.g. `sam` in your example) then

```
{% if sam %}   
    "sam" : "{{ sam }}"
{% else %}      
{%endif %}
```

You should probably pass your `uri` values as a list then do something like this in the template:

```
"uris":
[
    {% for uri in uris %}
    "{{ uri }}"
    {% endfor %}
]
```

If there are no `uri` values and you are not passing a list to `render.template` then you could omit the `"uris"` tag completely in a similar fashion to `sam`.

Comment: @T Burgis,  How do I add the uri to render.template.   "  payload = template.render(starttime=self.time[0], endtime=self.time[1], resolution=self.resolution, uris =uri_list )   "   this doesn't work